# How do I check parameter "param[:some_value]" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I know some ways to check if parameter is not nil

```
if param[:some_value]
if param[:some_value].present?
if !param[:some_value].nil?    #unless param[:some_value].nil? 
if !param[:some_value].blank?  #unless param[:some_value].blank?
```

Which one is correct and most popular? What is the difference between them?
I'd rather use `if param[:some_value]` because it is simplest and shorterst.

Comment: Which one is correct depends on your intent so what specifically are you trying to do? Those four aren't equivalent, there are subtle differences in there. And sometimes you might actually mean `param.has_key? :some_value`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are some differences between `nil?`, `blank?` and `present?`:

```
>> "".nil?
=> false
>> "".blank?
=> true
>> "".present?
=> false
>> " ".nil?
=> false
>> " ".blank?
=> true
>> " ".present?
=> false
```

Note that `present?` translates to `not nil and not blank`.  Also note that while `nil?` is provided by Ruby, `blank?` and `present?` are helpers provided by Rails.

So, which one to choose? It depends on what you want, of course, but when evaluating params[:some_value], you will usually want to check not only that it is not nil, but also if it is an empty string. Both of these are covered by `present?`.

Comment: Then what is the difference between `if param[:some_value]` and `if !param[:some_value].nil?`  ?

Comment: `if param[:some_value]` is **false**, if the value returned is `nil` or `false`, `!param[:some_value].nil?` on the other hand is **false** if and only if (*iff*) `param[:some_value]` returns `nil`.

Comment: Just to note, `present?` translates to `not blank?`. `blank?` itself checks for nil.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant cases are:

1. The hash lacks the key (and its value)
2. The hash has the value `nil` for the key
3. The hash has the value empty string (`""`) or the empty array (`[]`) for the key
4. The hash has some other value for the key

Depending on where you want to draw the line, use the appropriate method.

- 1 vs. 2, 3, 4: `!param.key?(:some_value)`
- 1, 2 vs. 3, 4: `param[:some_value].nil?`
- 1, 2, 3 vs. 4: `param[:some_value].blank?`
- 2, 3, 4 vs. 1: `param.key?(:some_value)`
- 3, 4 vs. 1, 2: `param[:some_value]`
- 4 vs. 1, 2, 3: `param[:some_value].present?`

Answer (score 2):

`if param[:some_value]` is the most common one.

But if you're working with boolean data (`true`,`false`) the best method
would be `if !param[:some_value].nil?`, because:

```
>> hash = {foo:false, bar:nil}

>> !! hash[:foo]
=> false
>> !! hash[:bar]
=> false

>> !! !hash[:foo].nil?
=> true
>> !! !hash[:bar].nil?
=> false
```

(`!!` returns the boolean value, which would be tested in an if-statement)

Also it could be important to test if the value is really nil, or if the key-value combo isn't defined. `key?(key)` does that for you.

```
>> hash ={foo:nil}

>> hash[:foo]
=> nil
>> hash[:not_there]
=> nil

>> hash.key?(:foo)
=> true
>> hash.key?(:not_there)
=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do, but I generally use these forms:

```
if param[:some_value]
  ...
end

# and
param[:some_value] && something
# or
param[:some_value] || somethinn
```

Of course all of them only work if the parameter can't be `false`. In that case I'd go for the `unless param[:some_value].nil?` version.

Comment: `Of course all of them only work if the parameter can't be false`. Really? I didn't know that. That is, if url contains `site.com/article/19.html?some_article=false` then `if param[:some_value]` won't be executed, right?

Comment: No, `some_article` should be the string `"false" then. But I've seen people turn that into booleans and store it back in `params`...